# Proofs on a dense in R set...

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let A be a dense in R set. Proof that the intersection of A with any non-empty open interval is a infinit set.

Thanks.

Comment: For R you mean the real line? You should learn using Latex to write it as $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A\cap (a,b)$ is a finite set, say $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ arranged in inreasing order than $A\cap (x_1,x_2)$ is empty and this is a contradiction.